# Duvida sobre utulização de procedure no Jasper Studio 6.3

Tags: stored-procedures, procedure, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

estou com um problema para chamar uma procedure pelo dataset do meu jasper.

JasperStudio 6.3
JasperServer 7.2.0

Utilizo banco postgres e a mesma está funcionando corretamente quando chamada lá, assim como funciona corretamente quando dada um "preview" dentro do próprio jasper.

O problema é quando o servidor vai chamar ela, que da um erro genérico de servidor.

Se alguém puder dar uma luz, não é possivel que não aceita a chamada da Procedure sendo que no preview ele consegue mapear corretamente.

Segue anexo imagem para melhor entendimento do problema.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]